# What is the PowerShell "Filter" command type?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I noticed something interesting today while inspecting the output of `Get-Command` and listing the items underneath the `Function:` provider. I don't see this used on any loaded built-ins, but one of my third party modules showed an interesting `CommandType` rather than the expected **Application**, **Function**, **Cmdlet**, or **Alias** types:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Filter          New-HashObject                                     3.3.2      Pscx
```

It is this function and this function only that I can find with this `CommandType`. I have never seen it before. I dug through the PowerShell docs as well and the only (nearly) direct reference I could find was the [FilterInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.filterinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) class, derived from [FunctionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.functioninfo?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0). Per its description, I can see that `FilterInfo`:

> Provides information about a filter that is stored in session state.

But that's the end of it, and is about as descriptive as what `FunctionInfo` is to a `Function`. I was able to find some other vague references to class names with Filter in the name, but these:

- Are all `string` typed and describe *Functions* (at least the ones I found are).
- Several have been removed from the latest version of the documentation, but are documented for 5.1.
- They looked like C++ documentation, not C# or VB.NET, despite being part of the PowerShell SDK documentation.

  - I know what C++/CLI is but *generally* C++ examples on .NET constructs are less common than C# or VB.NET, and even less so on documentation dealing with PowerShell.

What is a `Filter` command? Based on what I've found so far is this seems like some new construct for creating filters in lieu of string-based filtering that hasn't been documented, but these are also programmatic types and there is absolutely no information I can find on what a Filter in PowerShell means as an executable construct. The closest thing I can find is the [Input Filter Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/input-filter-parameters?view=powershell-7.1) document, which still only explains *string*-based filtering and its referenced [Supporting Wildcard Characters in Cmdlet Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/supporting-wildcard-characters-in-cmdlet-parameters?view=powershell-7.1) again goes into implementing string-based Filter parameters on cmdlets using wildcards.

Comment: Is it not this?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1#filters

Comment: That... is embarrassing. Yes, it looks like the answer to my question. In my defense, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=filter%20PowerShell%20commandtype does not yield that page as a result, nor are the other command types (well, that I know about) documented with under the Functions page. If you post that as an answer i'll accept it. Thank you

Comment: No reason to be embarrassed.  It is quite buried and terse. Your question about it is longer.  =D  It also does not seem to be widely used as you mentioned.

Comment: It does. Odd it didn't show up in the Ask Question list of existing questions or when i searched SO before asking. I guess as you mentioned it's not very widely used. Even google/bing was returning content about filters with `functions` and implementing `begin / process / end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [about_Functions > Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1#filters)

> A filter is a type of function that runs on each object in the pipeline. A filter resembles a function with all its statements in a Process block.

It's basically a simple construct similar to a function that will operate on pipeline input without all the advanced function setup

```
filter TodaysFiles{
    if ($_.LastWriteTime -gt [datetime]::Today) {$_ | select length, fullname}
}

dir | TodaysFiles
```